# How to import ES6 module allowing CORS policy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cors

I'm building a webpage and when the page loads I import a bunch of es6 code globally that will be used by the rest of the application. My javascript looks as follows:

```js
// main.js

Promise.all([
    import("Highcharts"),
    import("some other library") // etc...
]).then(() => {
    // run the rest of the code
})
```

My importmaps look like:

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "Highcharts": "https://code.highcharts.com/10.3.3/highcharts.js",
          "some other library": "some other CDN"
        }
      }
</script>
<script defer type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

When I run it locally everything works, however when I deploy the app to AWS I'm getting the following error on the front-end:

`Access to script at 'https://code.highcharts.com/10.3.3/highcharts.js' from origin 'MY-WEB-URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

How do I import CDN-provided code allowing CORS? Everything works if I add the script in my HTML as follows:

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.3.3/highcharts.js"></script>
```

However, then I do not have access to the `Highcharts` object in my modules and cannot manipulate it with javascript.

Comment: I do get back a `access-control-allow-origin: *` header when I request that script. I doubt it depends on the `referer` or `origin` request headers